# Integral of Bessel function with Gaussian over a quadratic

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration, bessel-functions

I need help with the following integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_0(ax)xe^{-bx^2}}{1-cx^2}dx   $$

Where $ J_0(x) $ is a Bessel function of the first kind (of zero order).

I've looked up a few books containing tables of integrals and can't find this exact one.

I tried using contour integration over a semi-circle with $ f(z) = \frac{J_0(az)ze^{-bz^2}}{1-cz^2} $ but because it's an odd function of z then the principle part of the integration disappears and I don't know what to do.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The integral does not converge for $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You see from @RonGordon's answer that for $c>0$ it is easy to "evaluate" the integral. It might be good if you could provide some context (where does this problem come from) and tell us what values you want the parameters $a,b,c$ to obtain.

Comment: It comes from parameterizing ocean eddies in an abstract sense so it's origins are not helpful. The constants are not important either to be honest, I care more about a functional form of the solution.

Comment: @TomBolton: the constants seem to be important as for $c>0$ the integral simply diverges. It also diverges for all $\text{Re} \,b <0$. So unless you tell us where in the complex plane your parameters are it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @Fabian: Ah I see what you mean now. All the constants a,b,c are real and positive.

Comment: @TomBolton: so the answer is simply infinity as there is a divergence for $x= c^{-1/2}$.

Comment: To echo the points made above: if $c$ is positive, your denominator explicitly vanishes at positive value of $x$. It seems unlikely that this makes sense in your setup.

Comment: Does that really mean there is no hope? My optimism comes from a paper by Qiong-Gui Lin 2013 where he produces a general result for integrating Bessel functions times some function: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10652469.2012.758119#.VGzuLck-jIU

Comment: In the paper, it makes it seem like its ok that the function has simple poles...

Comment: @TomBolton: If $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$, you may only compute the principal value of the integral. When $b=0$, that is not difficult through the Laplace transform.